# Is there an easier way to derive this equation for this mechanics problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, kinematics, rigid-transformation

We're given a semicircle whose total mass $M$ is evenly distributed along its contour and a little particle of mass $m$ is dropped from its top left corner as in the image below all over an horizontal plane. There is no friction between the semicircle and the particle nor between the semicircle and the ground (so no rolling without slipping!).

[image]

$P_0$ represents the particle at the start of the movement and $P$ represents it on a random position after the release of it.

The center of the semicircle is $O$.

The angles that I used to describe this crazy movement were $\theta = \angle P_0OA$ and $\alpha = AOP$ and, as I'm not that great with rigid body dynamics, I actually solved this problem using Lagrange's equations and I couldn't help but to notice that one of the equations that describe this movement is fairly simple:

$$2\frac gR \cos (\alpha) = (\ddot \theta + \ddot \alpha) 2\cos (\theta) - \pi \ddot \theta \sin(\theta+\alpha)$$

it is pretty remarkable that this equation does not involve the masses $m$ nor $M$ and I've been wondering if there is an easy way to get to this equation by analysing the momentum of the semicircle. But I struggled a bit with the acceleration of the system in a non inertial frame and I wonder if someone could hint on how to tackle it without Lagrange's equations.

This is the Lagrangian I got and I'm 100% sure that it is correct:

$$ \mathcal L (\theta, \alpha)= -\frac{R^2}{2(M+m)}(\frac 2{\pi}M \dot \theta \cos(\theta) + m \sin(\theta+\alpha)(\dot \theta + \dot \alpha))^2 + \frac{MR^2 \dot \theta ^2}2 + \frac{mR^2(\dot \theta + \dot \alpha)^2}2 + mgR\sin(\theta +\alpha) + \frac 2{\pi} MR\cos(\theta)g$$

EDIT: @eyeballfrog managed to turn that equation in a pendulum like equation:

$$\frac gR \sin\theta +(\pi/2)\ddot{\theta} - \cos\theta \ddot{x} = 0$$

where $x$ is the size of $OO_0$ (with signal), looks like a pendulum in a non inertial frame

Comment: Interesting result. Suppose the particle had zero mass, then the semi circle wouldn't budge, but the equation still holds. This suggests that it is more a kinematic relation than a dynamic one.

Comment: It is not remarkable at all that the equation is independent of $m$ and $M$.  As mentioned, this is an entirely kinematic—not dynamic—problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but it also has gravity on the equation

Comment: You don't need gravity to roll the semicircle... just push down on it.  (All this is a minor point, however.)

Comment: but how  could it be a purely geometric relationship between $\theta$ and $\alpha$? I think it is dynamics

Comment: What did you get for the Lagrangian?

Comment: oh boy, here we go. In terms of the angles, I've got this:

Comment: $\mathcal L (\theta, \alpha)= -\frac{R^2}{2(M+m)}(\frac 2{\pi}M \dot \theta \cos(\theta) + m \sin(\theta+\alpha)(\dot \theta + \dot \alpha))^2 + \frac{MR^2 \dot \theta ^2}2 + \frac{mR^2(\dot \theta + \dot \alpha)^2}2 + mgR\sin(\theta +\alpha) + \frac 2{\pi} MR\cos(\theta)g$

Comment: Hmm, I tried it myself and get something different. Also $\phi = \theta + \alpha$ makes more sense as a coordinate, as the two always appear together like that.

Comment: @eyeballfrog can you show me what you've done? Post some pics in the chat?

Comment: Calling 

$$
\cases{
O = (o,R)\\
P = O - R(\cos(\alpha+\theta),\sin(\alpha+\theta))\\
G = O + r_G(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)\\
I_G = M(R^2-r_G^2)\\
}
$$

we have the lagrangian

$$
L(o,\alpha,\theta) = \frac M2\|\dot G\|^2+\frac m2\|\dot P\|^2+\frac{I_G}{2}\dot\theta^2-\left(M G g+m P g\right)\hat{e}_y
$$

with $\hat{e}_y = (0,1)$. The movement equations derived from this lagrangian don't agree with those furnished on the OP. Why the difference?

Comment: @Cesareo can you show me the expression in terms of $\alpha$ and $\theta$ only?

Comment: $$
\ddot\alpha=\frac{2 \left(\left(R^2+r_G^2\right) \sin (\alpha+\theta)-R r_G \cos (\theta)\right) \left(2 m R \dot\alpha \dot\theta \cos (\alpha+\theta)+m R \dot\alpha^2 \cos(\alpha+\theta)+\dot\theta^2 (m R \cos (\alpha+\theta)-M r_G \sin (\theta))\right)+g \left(\cos (\alpha+\theta) \left(2 R^2 (m+M)+r_G^2 (2 m+M)\right)+R r_G ((m+2M) \sin (\theta)-m \sin (2 \alpha+\theta))-M r_G^2 \cos (\alpha-\theta)\right)}{R \left(m \left(R^2+r_G^2\right) \cos (2 (\alpha +\theta))+R^2 (m+2 M)+r_G^2 (m+M)-M r_G^2 \cos (2 \theta)\right)} 
$$

Comment: $$
\ddot\theta=\frac{r_G \left(-m R \sin (\alpha) \sin (2 \theta) \left(\dot\alpha+\dot\theta\right)^2+2 m R \cos (\alpha) \cos ^2(\theta) \left(\dot\alpha+\dot\theta\right)^2+g m \sin (2\alpha+\theta)-g (m+2 M) \sin (\theta )-M r_G \dot\theta^2 \sin (2 \theta)\right)}{m \left(R^2+r_G^2\right) \cos (2 (\alpha+\theta))+R^2 (m+2 M)+r_G^2 (m+M)-M
   r_G^2 \cos (2 \theta)}
$$

Comment: @Cesareo yeah I think the problem is on the KE of the shell. Even though you can make the distribution of speeds as translation + rotation around G, you can't decompose the total KE only in rotation + translation through a simple sum.

Comment: @Cesareo $T = \frac{M ||\dot G||^2}2 + \sum \frac{m_i v_i'^2}2$ is the expression for the KE of the shell wrt the ground, but $v'_i = v_i- \dot G$. We can however write $v_i = \dot G + \dot \theta r_{iG}$... your expression should be correct.

Comment: the good news is that our total KE of the shell is the same. In your notation it will be: $\frac{M \dot o^2}2 + \frac{Mr^2 \dot \theta ^2}2 + \frac 2{\pi} MR \dot o \dot \theta \cos (\theta)$

Comment: @Cesareo our Lagragians are the same, I don't know how your equations got so different than mine.